# Cannot call methods on varbinary Using SQL View & Geography

Tags: sql, geography, sql-view, sqlgeography

```sql
Select 
    r.Id,
    r.Date,
    r.Position.Lat Lat,
    r.Position.Long Lng,
    r.DriverId,
    r.VehicleId,
    --IsNull(t.DriverId, r.DriverId) DriverId,
    --v.Name GroupName,
    l.Name LayerName
From
    Operation.vw_AllRecord as r  --The View
    Inner Join @entityIds Ids 
        On Ids.Id = r.VehicleId
    Inner Join @LayerPointCache l
            ON r.Position.Lat Between MinY 
           And MaxY And r.Position.Long Between MinX And MaxX 
Where
    r.Date Between @StartDate And @EndDate And
    r.HasPosition = 1
```

there is error on this line

```sql
ON r.Position.Lat Between MinY And MaxY And r.Position.Long Between MinX And MaxX
```

saying:

> Cannot call methods on varbinary

Please note that `Operation.vw_AllRecord` is a view

Comment: what is about MinX, MaxX and MinY, MaxY.. Are they column of any function in database or some variables?

Comment: Declare @LayerPointCache Table(Name nvarchar(200), MinX float, MaxX float, MinY float, MaxY float)